# Lollipop graphics glitch

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-design

I have started programming using Material Design and I'm facing very weird graphic bug.

- I have 2 activities A and B.
- Activity B has 3 Fragments.
- I start with Activity A → click on item → start Activity B.

Basically Activity A contains a Fragment with a RecyclerView. 2 Fragments of 3 of Activity B does also contain RecyclerView. Once I go back from Activity B (where the Fragment with RecyclerView is active) to Activity A by pressing back navigation button, here's what happens:

[image: Bugged screenshot]

When I scroll a bit, everything repairs.

[image: Ok screenshot]

I'm using newest support libraries (21.0.3) and build tools. Bug appears on Android 5.0 and 5.0.1.
Logcat does not report any errors or warnings.

I do not override any Activity transactions, also I don't work with any Paint, Drawable, etc.
Anyone faced this bug, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: We're seeing the same thing. Did you resolve this?

Comment: It disappeared after I updated support libraries to newer version. Now it's gone.